# How to JSON.parse and ignore the array indices?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have this sample string which I want to parse as an Object

```
const payload = "{\"teamIds\":[584,585,586]}";

console.log(JSON.parse(payload))
```

However the result automatically adds the indices:

```
teamIds:
  0: 584,
  1: 585,
  2: 586
```

How do I get rid of the indices in this case and just keep `[584,585,586]` as is?

## EDIT

Coming from a PHP background, I thought this one was possible. Nevertheless, thank you for all your help.

Comment: What you're seeing is a feature of the console.log function; all arrays in javascript are going to have an index associated with each number.  What you're seeing is just one visualization of it.

Comment: When you perform a `JSON.parse`, you're asking to turn your string into a JSON object. If you want `[584,585,586]` to be represented as a string in the resulting object, you need to include double/single quotes around it in your original string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, that's how arrays work, they need to have indexes for values that are automatically set if you don't provide any of yours. 
That's just how it works, in javascript, you can assign index, but it then becomes an object, not an array, but there cannot be a value in an array without index.

Comment: I think you mean it becomes an object.

Comment: JSON is an object, it is pointless to say JSON object ad JSON is short for JavaScript OBJECT Notation.

Comment: The operative word is "notation". JSON is the string that you create from an object or array when you call `JSON.stringify()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const payload = "{\"teamIds\":[584,585,586]}";

console.log('['+JSON.parse(payload).teamIds.toString()+']')
```